# Context.PageMode is not working in Experience editor

Tags: experience-editor, ajax

When I load the page in Experience Editor for the first time, I am able to get `Context.pagemode.IsExperienceEditor` as `true`. We have a few `ajax` begin forms on the page. When I call any method in the page we will be validating a filter and if it's Experience Editor then we allow access to the method, I am getting `Context.PageMode.IsExperienceEditor` as `false` invalidation method.

As a result, the `302 redirection` happens resulting in `CORS error`. This was working fine earlier in all environments. But currently not working in a `QA environment`.

**Note:** We didn't make changes to the code at all.

Comment: DId you try this in javascript, where you have ajax calls - 
var isPageEditor = function(){
    return !!(Sitecore && Sitecore.PageModes && Sitecore.PageModes.PageEditor);
};
 
if(isPageEditor()) {
    // Write your logic here
}

Comment: I was able to resolve this issue by checking for sc_mode=edit in UrlReferrer.

Comment: Add this as an answer and accept that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by checking for `sc_mode=edit` in **UrlReferrer**

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a `Glass Mapper` in your project solution then you can use the below code snippet to find out `IsExperienceEditor` or not:

```
 var isInEditMode = Html.Glass().IsInEditingMode;
```

You can define the above variable on top of your `.cshtml view` code and assign it to any HTML hidden field.

```
    @{
       var isInEditMode = Html.Glass().IsInEditingMode;
     }
    <input type="hidden" id="isEditMode" name="isEditMode" value="@isInEditMode" />
```

Now you can retrieve the above value into your `javascript/JS` code as:

```
let isExperienceMode = this.$el.querySelector('#isEditMode')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code in the view and pass parameter value to Ajax call.

```
@{
    var value = Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsExperienceEditor;
}
```

and you can use this value in hidden field.